# (PYTHON) iterating through a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
randomLetters = {'j': 0, 'p': 1, 'x': 2}
corLetters = {'t': 0, 'h': 1, 'e': 2}
```

I want my "for loop" to iterate through the dictionary and replace the "random letters" Keys with "corLetters" keys and output to a string. This is how I have it so far:

```
for k in randomLetters.values():
    attempt = strOne.replace(randomLetters.keys()[k], corLetters.keys()[k]) 
print("\nThe first attempt at deciphering is: ")
print(attempt)
```

When I print this out, I expect the output to be "the" but instead I get "jpe". Can someone show me how to correctly iterate using a for loop and output it to the terminal as a string?

Comment: Please don't add fake "tags" to your title. Stack Overflow has _real_ tags, and they are sufficient. The fact that your title is rejected with out that "tag" is a good indicator that your question already has an answer, or needs refinement.

Comment: You should probably rethink your attempt. If you're using a dictionary and your key or value is an equivalent of a list index there is a good chance you shouldn't be using dictionaries.
As stated above, you should work more on your question, it is unclear and probably already solved.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement Substitution cipher. I suggest you to use dictionary as `{'j': 't', 'p': 'h', 'x': 'e'}`

Comment: Each time through the loop you're starting from the original `strOne`, not the result of the previous replacement.

Comment: So the final value of `attempt` just contains the last replacement.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to do is only know the output:

```
randomLetters = {'j': 0, 'p': 1, 'x': 2}
corLetters = {'t': 0, 'h': 1, 'e': 2}
attempt=" "
for h,k in randomLetters.items():
        for i,x in corLetters.items():
            if k==x:
                attempt=attempt+i

print("\nThe first attempt at deciphering is: "+attempt)
```

> The output is: the

But, if you want also to change the Keys on randomLetters:

```
randomLetters = {'j': 0, 'p': 1, 'x': 2}
corLetters = {'t': 0, 'h': 1, 'e': 2}
attempt=" "
for h,k in randomLetters.items():
        for i,x in corLetters.items():
            if k==x:
                randomLetters[i] = randomLetters.pop(h)
                attempt=attempt+i

print("\nThe first attempt at deciphering is: "+attempt)
```

> The output is: "the" and the randomLetter dictionary is "{'t': 0, 'h': 1, 'e': 2}"

Hope it help, have a nice day,

David